# error in using BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm newbie to HTML parsers. I'm actually trying to parse the source code of the webpage with url (http://www.quora.com/How-many-internships-are-necessary-for-a-B-Tech-student). I'm trying to get the answer_count.

I tried it in the following way:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

q = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(q)
divs = soup.find_all('div',class_='answer_count')
```

But I get the list 'divs' as empty. Why is it so? Where am I wrong? How do I implement it to get the result as '2 Answers'?

Comment: I didn't found any answer_count class?

Comment: There is a answer_count class in the source code!                  Here's a small patch: <div class="answer_count">2 Answers<span id="ld_bdnqjl_196692"></span></div>

Comment: I agree with MA1, there is no `answer_count` in the source that I load. I think you are looking at the source from being logged in as opposed to what urllib2 grabs. Try looking at the source from incognito mode in chrome to see if you still find the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't have the same page as us on your browser (because you are logged in or so).

When I look at the webpage you provided with Google Chrome, there is nowhere 'answer_count' in the source code. So if Google chrome doen't find it, BeautifulSoup won't either

Comment: I woulds suggest to use the python 'requests' library. You'll be enable to log in from within your script to any website